# proofs based on least square estimators (simple linear regression)

Tags: statistics, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

Suppose that we have independent samples ${(x_i,y_i ):i=1,⋯,n}$ which are assumed to follow $ y_i=β_0+β_1 x_i+ε_i $ where $\epsilon_i$  are i.i.d. from $N(0,\sigma^2)$ . 
Suppose that $b_0$ and $b_1$ are the least square estimators of $b_0$ and $b_1$ respectively. Define $y ̂_i=b_0+b_1 x_i$ and $e_i=y_i-y ̂_i$.

Prove each of the following:

1. $$1/n \sum_{i=1}^n y ̂_i =y ̅ $$
2. $$\sum_{i=1}^n e_i =0$$
3. $$\sum_{i=1}^n (y ̂_i-y ̅ )e_i=0 $$

I know that I should use this fact but I could not figure it out till now:
$$ y ̂_i=b_0+b_1 x_i=y ̅+b_1 (x_i-x ̅) $$

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

All these results stem from the first order condition, namely, as you are minimizing 
$$
\sum ( y_i - \beta_0 - \beta_1x_i) ^2,
$$
then by the first derivative w.r.t. $\beta_0$ you have 
$$
-2\sum ( y_i - \hat \beta_0 - \hat \beta_1x_i)=0,   
$$
as $\hat y_i = \hat \beta_0 - \hat \beta_1x_i$, then 
$$
\sum ( y_i - \hat y_i)=0 \to 1/n \sum y_i = 1/n \sum\hat y_i.
$$
Next, note that $e_i = y_i - \hat y_i$, thus 
$$
\sum ( y_i - \hat y_i)= \sum e_i = 0.
$$
For the third one, use the fact that $\bar{y} =\hat \beta_0 + \beta_1 \bar x$, and $ \sum x_i ( y_i - \hat \beta_0 - \hat \beta_1 x_i ) = \sum x_i e_i  =0 $, which stems from the partial derivative w.r.t. $\beta_1$.